# awk line break after each file

Tags: arrays, awk, printf

With this script every field is printed out according to the longest word of the current file, but needs to have a line break every file. How can this be achieved?

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\n"}FNR=NR{a[i++]=$0; if(length($0) > length(max)) max=$0;l=length(max)}  END{ for(j=1; j<=i;j++) printf("%-"(l+1)"s,",a[j-1])}' file1 file2 >outfile
```

file1

```
HELLO
WORLD
SOUTH IS
WARM
NORTH IS
COLD
```

file2

```
HELLO
WORLD
SOUTH
WARM
NORTH
COLD
```

output

```
HELLO     ,WORLD     ,SOUTH IS  ,WARM      ,NORTH IS  ,COLD      
HELLO ,WORLD ,SOUTH ,WARM  ,NORTH ,COLD
```

Comment: Add `\n` to the end of every line you are printing. I think that the `ORS` will be used only when you use `print` and not with `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking for, but perhaps you just want:

```
FNR==1 {print "\n"}
```

Which will print a newline whenever it starts reading the first line of a file.  Make sure this pattern/action is before any others so that the newline prints before any other action prints anything for the first line of the current file.  (This does not appear to apply in your case, since no such action exists.)

Answer (score 0):

Took me some time, got it solved with this script.

```
awk '{ NR>1 && FNR==1 ? l=length($0) && a[i++]= "\n" $0 : a[i++]=$0 }
{if(NR>1 && FNR==1) for(e=(i-c);e<=(i-1);e++) b[e]=d ;c=FNR; d=l }
{ if( length($0) > l) l=length($0)+1 } 
END{for(e=(i-c+1);e<=i;e++) b[e]=d; for(j=1;j<=i;j++) printf("%-"b[j]"s,",a[j-1] )}' infiles* >outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
function beginfile (file) {
    split("", a)
    max = 0
    delim = ""
}

function endfile (file) {
    for (i = 1; i <= lines; i++) {
        printf "%s%-*s", delim, max, a[i]
        delim = " ,"
    }
    printf "\n"
}

FILENAME != _oldfilename \
     {
         if (_oldfilename != "")
             endfile(_oldfilename)
         _oldfilename = FILENAME
         beginfile(FILENAME)
     }

     END   { endfile(FILENAME) }

{
    len = length($0)
    if (len > max) {
        max = len
    }
    a[FNR] = $0
    lines = FNR
}
```

To run it:

```
chmod u+x filename
./filename file1 file2
```

Note that in `gawk` you can do `delete a` instead of `split("", a)`. GAWK 4 has builtin `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE`.